# How to best way to extrapolate sample size results to overall population

Tags: algorithm, data-science

Lets assume we get 200K customer calls per day. All the calls are scanned for particular patterns or words to categorize them as "Potential complaints". There is manual process be a team to test 1% of them randomly and identify the root cause which is then sent to product team to remediate. The questions I have are:

1. How can I extrapolate the root cause to overall population?
2. What is the best way to measure the effectiveness of remediation?